# Internet Explorer 7+8 jQuery Error with infiniteCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Hai guise! I am having a spot of trouble with some jQuery I am using, this was previously working but I have made many developments since then and tried to track back to find out what the issue was, but I am unsuccessful - hence, my presence on here. Anyway, I am getting some JS errors in both IE7 and IE8 with the catch my frame jQuery infiniteCarousel plugin, I am literally pulling my hair out over this as when you remove any reference to this everything works beautifully.

[Here](http://www.bravecreative.co.uk/index.php) is a link to the page.

If anyone can shed any light on the matter you would be a life saver!

Comment: I'd suggest you try running with the full-fat, non-minified version of jQuery and plug-ins

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm! Could you possibly explain why including the 'full-fat' version of jQuery could make any sort of difference at all?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the [jQuery infinite carousel](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/08/27/jquery-infinite-carousel-plugin-1-2-released/) plugin is poorly written and the minifaction process requires well formed JavaScript. If you take his code and run it through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) you'll see it needs dozens of fixes before it's likely to minimize properly. This is something the author of the plugin needs to rectify.

Answer (score 0):

Although it isn't throwing any errors, it seems that the plugin is loosing track of the elements. A possible solution would be to hook into the start and complete events and stop all the button events until it has completed the animation.

Alternatively, use this plugin instead: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/